# View Informix SE database files

Tags: informix

I have a few .dat and .idx files inside a .dbs folder, so presumably these were created using Informix SE. I need a way to view or extract info from these files.

I have Informix SE 7.25 installed in a Windows platform but I don't know how to read those files. Do I use dbexport.exe that comes with Informix SE or dbaccess.exe? I tried to have a play around with both but don't know how to use them properly.

Can anyone help me with this problem?

Answer (score 1):

If the files are in a directory `dbase.dbs`, then you should be able to use:

```
dbexport dbase
```

to generate a directory `dbase.exp` containing a schema file `dbase.sql` and a series of `.unl` files — the unloaded data from each table in the database.

That's by far the easiest way to get the data.

The data format is Informix's UNLOAD format — usually pipe-delimited, backslash-escaped files with one logical line per record.  There are tedious wrinkles in the data format, but most of them won't affect you.

It's relatively straight-forward (but by no means trivial) to convert the data into CSV format — and other formats would be possible to, with greater or lesser amounts of work.

Using DB-Access would be a labour of love — it would be a lot harder work.  You'd probably generate a list of tables from the database (with DB-Access), then munge that output into a series of UNLOAD statements, which you'd then run into DB-Access again to get the actual data.  It can certainly be done; you should aim to avoid having to do it that way.

If the database is incomplete — for example, the system catalog is missing — then all is not lost, but the work gets far harder as you have to read the raw `.dat` files and you have to deduce the schema for the tables.  That is hard to do 100% reliably.  If you have the schema, then I have tools to get the data out of the database — contact me (see my profile).

Comment: I tried that on the command prompt and I get an error "- 404 - The cursor or statement is not available". What does this error mean?

How does dbexport know which directory the .dbs folder is in? The .dbs folder is in a location different to the main directory of the Informix SE installation.

Comment: It assumes the current directory first, then in a directory in `DBPATH` environment variable.    I'm not sure what the error means.  It's ominous.

Comment: I have the dbase.dbs folder in C:\Users\...\Documents. I am in that directory in the command prompt and when I try dbexport dbase I get that error. I added DBPATH to the environment variables and it still doesn't work.

Comment: That's puzzling. There are a couple of tests we can try. (1) Can you run DB-Access against the database?  Create a file `check.sql` containing `select tab name from systables where rabid >= 100` and run a command `dbaccess dbase check` and see if you get a list of table names. If that works, there must be a problem with DB-Export.  (2) do you have either `bcheck` or `secheck`?  If so, maybe you should run it on each of the `.idx` files in the database.  Check its usage; there may be a way to do it all at once.  Again, you're looking for error messages.

Comment: For (1), I have created check.sql with that line in the C:\Users\...\Documents folder. I ran the suggested command after cding to the C:\Users\...\Documents directory, but I get the same error. To use dbaccess correctly, do I need to change any settings using setnet32.exe? Also, the database files were created in another computer running a Unix based OS, but migrated to Windows. Will this have any impact on the error I am seeing? For (2) I used secheck (file).idx and found a few errors on some of the files that state "ERROR: 1 missing index node pointer(s) Fix index node tree list ?"

Comment: Do you know what type of machine it was created on?  If it was another x86 machine, there shouldn't be a problem. If it was a SPARC or PowerPC machine, there could be problems. Your question about `setnet32` has me stumped; I've no idea. I've not used Informix on Windows. However, the error is a post-connection error so it shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: The occasional errors from`secheck` may not be very serious. Ideally, they'd not be there.  And they may now be fixed.

Comment: I have no expertise on computer architectures but I believe it is an SGI Octane machine running IRIX 6.5 OS, so it is fairly old - I sent you an email earlier to your gmail account.